# Matlab tcpip server receiving data from c program

Tags: c, matlab, tcpclient, tcp, tcpserver

I am trying to write a Matlab code that will receive data from an outside c program and graph it.  The data is in text format.  In my past attempts every time the connection is made, but no message is received by the matlab program even though I can verify that is was sent.  Basically I am looking for an answer on the correct way in Matlab to retrieve data from a TCP connection that was sent from a c program.

```
function tcp_testing()
    t = tcpip('localhost',7220,'NetworkRole','server')

    % Set size of receiving buffer, if needed.
    set(t, 'InputBufferSize', 30000); 

    % Open connection to the server. 
    fopen(t); 

    % Transmit data to the server (or a request for data from the server). 
    fprintf(t, 'GET /'); 

    % Pause for the communication delay, if needed. 
    pause(1) 

    % Receive lines of data from server 
    while (get(t, 'BytesAvailable') > 0)
        t.BytesAvailable 
        DataReceived = fscanf(t) 
    end 
end
```

Comment: No - edit the code into the question so that it can be formatted!

Comment: I haven't incorporated graphing yet.  I am just focusing on the TCP connection.

Comment: any reason you're doing this inside a function instead of a script?

Comment: Eventually I will be including variables for the port number and so on, but for now I just wanted to hard code it for testing purposes.